# Does using of 2 different ram affects the performance?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3

I have a DDR3 RAM of 1333MHz of 2GB on my motherboard (Asus H61M-k).Can i insert another 4GB DDR3 stick ? or insert 2GB DDR3 instead of 4GB ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the memory access will be penalized. If you use different sized RAM modules you'll have just single channel memory access. If you use 2 modules of the same size (and the best parameters too), you'll get dual channel access.

If parameters of both modules aren't the same, set settings according to the worse one.

Answer (score 0):

Out of preference you want two matching sticks of RAM, but coming from one stick of RAM to two you will, at worst, not notice any lower performance but should get at least some kind of benefit. Either your memory will be faster (dual channel) or you will have more memory making your system more efficient or both. Either way more than 2GB is good.

Going from one stick to two will not "penalise" your performance but with mismatched sizes you may not be getting the full benefit of dual-channel memory which can significantly increase memory bandwidth. This is not really a problem as for a lot of tasks (web browsing and word processing) you will notice almost no difference between single and dual channel modes.

Having mismatched sizes on an Intel processor means you *might* be working in "[flex](https://superuser.com/questions/769529/memory-runs-at-flex-memory-mode)" memory mode, where you get the benefits of dual-channel memory up to a certain point (the smallest memory module size multiplied by 2) and then single channel for the rest. In your example this would mean you have 4GB (2GB + 2GB) of dual channel RAM and 2GB of single channel.

Whichever way you go you will probably see a performance boost from the extra RAM. Get whichever you can afford.