# Custom PC Won't POST After RAM Upgrade

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

A few days ago, my custom computer broke. I will include all information possible in case some of it may help. Please let me know if I need to post more information. The last thing I did while it was functional was cloning my main SSD (running Garuda Linux) to an internal HDD for a backup, then I rebooted to the HDD to test. Then I shut it down (but the PSU was still on) and disconnected the HDD from both power and SATA. SATA is hotpluggable so it shouldn't have been a problem, but it could have been.

Next, I flipped the switch on the PSU to turn off all power to the computer then installed an extra stick of RAM (bought from eBay, more information at the end of the post). I have heard that installing three DIMMs will make the system use dual-channel until it uses up all of the first two RAM sticks then switch to single-channel on the third, but this may have caused problems (Edit: Apparently this is only for Intel). This was on carpet because I didn't want to move my computer for such a small thing, so I could have caused an ESD problem.

I then booted into the BIOS to make sure XMP was configured correctly and everything was detected as 3200MT/s RAM. I didn't check the CAS latency. I then selected the RAM speed option and the BIOS froze. The mouse wouldn't move and the arrow keys wouldn't change anything. I held the power button to shut it down. I booted into the BIOS again and tried again, and the same thing happened. I then tried to boot into the OS (Garuda Linux) on the SSD (250GB Samsung 870 Evo) and it froze with some text on the screen--I forgot to take a picture of the text. I then tried to reboot into Windows, which froze at a black screen. On my next reboot, the computer stopped POSTing. The fans would spin (the GPU fan even sped up and slowed down in a pattern similar to the beginning of the boot process), but nothing would display on the screen and my keyboard wouldn't initialize.

Once I realized how big of a problem it was, I removed the RAM stick. Unfortunately, this did not help. Resetting the CMOS did not help either. I then replaced every part of the system with a known-working part except the CPU, motherboard, and RAM, which I didn't have extras of (yes, the CMOS battery works). I have tried each stick of RAM in each slot to eliminate all possible variables. I have also removed and re-installed the CPU and cooler. Nothing helped.

Finally, I connected a buzzer that I had in another system. It had three beeps, paused at the same time as the GPU fan slowed down, then gave another three beeps. The AMI BIOS beep codes say that three beeps is a dead RAM stick, so I once again replaced the DIMM I was using with each of the other DIMMS and tried each one in every slot. Every one had the same error.

Based on this information, I decided that it must be either the RAM or the motherboard that was dead. It could be the CPU, but that seemed unlikely. Does anybody recognize the symptoms? Could it be the RAM stick that caused the problem or did I cause it? Was it the CPU, RAM, or motherboard that died?

Specs:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600

Motherboard: ASRock B450M Pro4

RAM:

- First kit: G.Skill Ripjaws V 16GB (8GBx2) CL16 DDR4-3200
- Upgrade kit: G.Skill Ripjaws V 8GB (8GBx1) CL19 DDR4-3600 (not perfectly identical but it should be close enough)

PSU: EVGA 450 BR

GPU: XFX Radeon R7 260X

Comment: “I have heard that installing three DIMMs will make the system use dual-channel until it uses up all of the first two RAM sticks then switch to single-channel on the third, but this may have caused problems.” - Where did you hear this because it’s absolutely false. We need to know which slots was your original configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound Intel has a [flex memory mode](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005657/boards-and-kits.html#flex) that does essentially what OP describes. When and where and on what devices it is enabled on is not explicitly stated though. It also appears to work across 3 sticks per https://superuser.com/questions/769529/memory-runs-at-flex-memory-mode

Comment: @Mokubai - The accepted answer states that, “You must have an equal capacity on both channels to run full dual channel.”, and that is not the case for the author so their system is running in single channel